# MS-Excel, change default custom formatting?

Tags: excel, date, format, default

If you enter 20/11 into a cell excel automatically applies a default custom format to 20-Nov (dd-mmm) on the cell.

How does one prevent this default behaviour from happening or modify it to yyyy/mm/dd **without** manually formatting cells?

Thanks

Comment: try to enter `'20/11` instead of `20/11`